# Did the Dallas Cowboys's Jeff Heath practice kicking at all since high school?

Tags: american-football

On 22nd October 2017, the Dallas Cowboys's kicker, [Dan Bailey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Bailey_(American_football)), was injured during [their game against the San Francisco 49ers](http://www.espn.com/nfl/recap?gameId=400951619). For the rest of the game, [strong safety Jeff Heath handled the kicking duties](https://www.si.com/nfl/2017/10/22/cowboys-safety-jeff-heath-backup-kicker-dan-bailey). While Heath kicked for his high school team, had he done any kicking practice since then?

Comment: It's very unlikely that any reliable answer is possible, though speculation is likely. If it was *unclear* before, it's *primarily opinion-based* now.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from [the official Cowboys site](http://www.dallascowboys.com/news/2017/10/22/bailey-hurt-heath-makes-kicking-cameo-first-time-high-school):

> [Heath] got a little [kicking] practice in training camp and last October

and from [NBC Sports](http://profootballtalk.nbcsports.com/2017/10/22/jeff-heath-has-longest-kick-by-non-kicker-since-1979/), referring to the "last October" incident above:

> Heath did kick during practice the following week, the first time he had kicked with a snapper and a holder since high school.

so he has definitely practiced since high school.